# problems appending() page in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to append a "page" in JQuery mobile that is not currently in view on my device. The problem is that it will not work.

If I use this method -

```
<a href="" onclick="clearProducts();" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

This will work, however its slow and not very good to look at. As it will first remove the elements from the page and then transition to the previous page. Giving the impression that its slow and buggy.

Is there a way to transition backwards first and then out of view remove the elements from the previous page?

Thanks

Comment: Whats inside clearProducts()?

Comment: `This will work`. What will work? We have no idea what `clearProducts()` does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are re-loading a page that is being brought into the DOM via AJAX then you can set the `reloadPage` property of the `$.mobile.changePage()` option object to `true` which allows you to transition to the same page while refreshing it's content:

```
function clearProducts() {
    $.mobile.changePage('/path/to/page.html', {
        reloadPage : true
    });
}
```

Here is the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html